The Determinant and the Invertibility of Matrices
In the text I am reading, the determinant is defined to have the property that $A$ is invertible if and only if $det(A) \neq 0$.
Since this is a biconditional statement, that means that: $A$ is invertible $\implies det(A) \neq 0$ and the converse $det(A) \neq 0 \implies A$ is invertible.
Clearly if $A$ is invertible $det(A) \neq 0$ since $AA^{-1} = I$ and $det(A)det(A^{-1}) = det(I) = 1$.
However, the converse is less clear to me. My thoughts are that if $det(A) \neq 0$ then the rows and columns of $A$ are linearly independent. I know that one can find the inverse matrix of a matrix $A$ by considering the augmented matrix $(A | I)$ and row reducing $A$ to $I$ while applying the same elementary row operations to $I$. Then the right partition of the augmented matrix will be $A^{-1}$.
I believe the fact that $det(A) \neq 0$ giving us that the rows of the matrix are linearly independent implies that $A^{-1}$ exists because $RREF(A)$ will attain the identity matrix since each row is linearly independent, therefore we will be able to achieve an inverse matrix through the aforementioned method.
Is this the reason that the converse of the biconditional is true? It seems to be so to me but I want to know for sure. Any insight or alternative ways of looking at it would be greatly appreciated. I would also like to know if there are other ways to prove this biconditional not including the way I explored.

What text are you reading? I ask because that "definition" does not uniquely determine the function $\det$. You can make your line of reasoning work but you'd need to fill in details to make it solid.

@blargoner I am reading Elementary Linear Algebra by Ron Larson

This "non-zero determinant implies invertibility" direction can be proven by observing that
\begin{align*}
A\operatorname{adj}(A) = \det(A)I_{(n)}, \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}
where $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is the adjugate matrix of $A$. Can you finish the argument now?
Details

 If $\det(A) \neq 0$, then $\eqref{1}$ can be rewritten as \begin{align*} A\left(\operatorname{adj}(A)/\det(A)\right) = I_{(n)},\end{align*} which by definition implies that $A$ is invertible and $A^{-1} = \operatorname{adj}(A)/\det(A)$. Conversely, if $A$ is invertible, then there exists $B$ such that $AB = I_{(n)}$, taking determinants on both sides yields $\det(A)\det(B) = \det(I_{(n)}) = 1$, hence $\det(A)$ cannot equal to $0$.


$A$ is invertible $\implies det(A) \neq 0$ since $adj(A) = det(A)A^{-1}$. Since $adj(A)$ will contain nonzero entries, it must be that $det(A) \neq 0$.
In the other direction $det(A) \neq 0 \implies A$ is invertible since the quantity $\frac{Aadj(A)}{det(A)} = I$ will attain a defined value.
Is that it? My only doubt is that part about the cofactor matrix containing nonzero entries, that seems to make sense but I can't verify it.

@MattKuehr Your argument of the "non-zero determinant $\implies$ invertibility" is correct. The other direction, is not so tangent.  See the updates of my answer for a correct argument. Note that to prove this direction, we actually do not even need to use the identity $(1)$ (the argument you used in the OP is actually correct :)).

I see that now. I think what I failed to appreciate at first is that $\frac{Aadj(A)}{det(A)} = I$ implies that $A^{-1}$ is precisely $\frac{adj(A)}{det(A)}$ for $det(A) \neq 0$. That's a very cool result, thanks for your answer!
While you're at it, do you mind telling me if my initial proof in the question is correct or if there is a hole in it, particularly with the converse.

I think the statement "I believe the fact that $\det(A) \neq 0$
giving us that the rows of the matrix are linearly independent" in your proof is not solid.

Is that because you think it is circular reasoning, or you think that is not a property of the determinant?

@MattKuehr Yes, it is kind of circular. Equally important, it is not necessary and inefficient (suppose it is logically correct)!
